# Get JSON object from URL using PHP

Tags: php, json, get, file-get-contents

I have a URL that gives different responses in JSON. I need to get the response using PHP and display target_url.
I did it successfully with this code.

```php
<?php
        $content = file_get_contents("https://code.directadvert.ru/show.cgi?adp=5357330&json=22");
        $content = utf8_encode($content);
        $result = json_decode($content, true);
        $url = $new['target_url'];

        foreach($result['news'] as $new) {
            echo $new['target_url'];
        }
?>
```

But I get only one of two identical answers. And every time I have to receive it differently. What could be the problem?

Comment: there is only one item

Comment: yes, but it should be different on every request

Answer (score 1):

You already have the JSON .. No need for a loop ..  Just drill down to the URL ..

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents("https://code.directadvert.ru/show.cgi?adp=5357330&json=22");
    $content = utf8_encode($content);
    $result = json_decode($content, true);

    $url = $result['news'][0]['target_url'];
    
    echo $url;
```

When you `json_decode`  -- Your `$result` becomes:

```
Array
(
    [news] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10906072
                    [pubdate] => 1602148428
                    [site_name] => fashion2news.com
                    [img] => https://cdn.directadvert.ru/cdn/images/100x100/40/8154740.jpg
                    [target_url] => https://fashion2news.com/tops-tees/diana-gurckaja-pritvorjalas-slepoj-40-let/?utm_medium=MarketGid&utm_source=MarketGid&utm_campaign=MarketGid&utm_term={widget_id}&utm_content=3219275&MarketGid
                    [rating] => 3
                    [title] => Ëîæü è öèíèçì ãîäàìè: ñòðàíà ñìîëêëà, óçíàâ, êåì îêàçàëàñü Ãóðöêàÿ
                    [created] => 1602148428
                    [url] => https://code.directadvert.ru/click/?x=Z8162cWaXn9LS96s2B_LJkN-p8fHQJjfLQ_0_mz4prYJYHjAAs3ju0g8WZ7WYJ_XhxC6dJJXzv-ZQOEYs6qWU1S2E0tjHoxxwhTmEUQ8XxOjvXW_zkKVkGbwg8OyXFW3vtcNSjmyV4BUu7cG9lMNBNiQh7x4WZBMGf9ODf60XOQZJhHU_lLugd4xKLFyqn8qGam46cVP-jnkQfINq3KkvSWh0rr9Q0TJtsKda-Cny04r-XGSb0cSKtKsHnjgkUq51iLgqMavsf-Z2Dp7exnyDA40tNIEKvf-ovZQCZvc3vz1A4f0fTfEtwlQyAV9MlIaDu7-2Lijh0Y1Tmox76ipgGXYHPyRVGpKD2E8Gh5wymj9jVVnMmIEYIqnIeTW0FHf6CLaV1hbziS8reZmfidytR79XxVWIO3puMtYk72qpnR0HcIj2dR8DhkbdC_K6Li0p_k7A5wRmaSF4L4SkyxkihSvV7V-gJif-CgYEzldqB1CkePDs1RWnD3ZTANj8m2FGBBxPPNsWqgROhAAkDLatuyBfYnCB4DSNotVyBNe6oY
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's better that way. But my problem remained, there are still two identical links in the answer. This should not be so, if you try to get json from the browser, the answers will always be different.